# Detect a bluetooth device using android-beacon-library

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, detect, beacon

I am using 
[android-beacon-library](https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library)
 to discover nearby Beacons and it is work fine and very reliable. Is it possible to use the same library to detect the Bluetooth signal of an Android device? I couldn't find any good reliable method to discover the nearby Bluetooth devices, that's why I want to use this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library is optimized to detect a very specific kind of Bluetooth LE device -- a beacon as the library name would suggest.  It is not designed to detect more general non-beacon Bluetooth devices.

It is also possible to use the library to make Android devices transmit a beacon signal.  If they do so, then the same library on other devices will detect those beacon transmissions.