# Activate android app upon bluetooth connection without foreground service on android 8 and above (android auto does it)

Tags: android, bluetooth, auto, foreground-service, android-auto

**Background:**
I've seen android auto being able to activate itself without using a foreground service after my phone was connected with my car. I got the code kind of running using a foreground service (works on my Pixel One) but i have to display a permanent notification, which is very annoying to some users. Also it doesn't work on other android phones, where the foreground service is still killed.

The current problem is, that android 8 and above kill any kind of background service after 15 minutes.

I've looked at android BLE using [this](https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-2-47a3cdaade07) and the android beacon library (which does not work according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956024/detect-a-bluetooth-device-using-android-beacon-library)). Currently im using the annoying foregroudn service and android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED

**What i want to do:**
I want my app to be called (broadcast, service) when a specific bluetooth device got connected with the phone (like a car). This should also work when the app was not opened for the last hours or even days.

Thank you for any tips in advance

Comment: Trying to do pretty much the same. I've successfully been able to get a broadcast receiver to be called upon device discovery in a separate process but I seem to be very limited to what I can actually do at this point, having issues using network etc. Did you even find a solution?

Comment: Yes I did. As it turns out the Bluetooth Intent is whitelisted and the app is woken up when a manifest receiver is registered.